# Inserting a bunch of data trough the Content Provider

Tags: android, sqlite, android-contentprovider, resultset, bulkinsert

I successfully inserted a huge ResultSets into my tables (I am using sqlite) like this:

```
public void insertRSData(ResultSet rs) throws SQLException {
    this.mDb.beginTransaction();
    try {
        this.mDb.delete(DATABASE_TABLE, null, null);
        while (rs.next()) {
            ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
            cv.put(ROW_ID, rs.getInt("id"));
            cv.put(ROW_NAME, rs.getString("name"));
            Date dNow = new Date();
            cv.put(ROW_DATE_UPD, dNow.toString());
            this.mDb.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, cv);
        }
        this.mDb.setTransactionSuccessful();
    } finally {
        this.mDb.endTransaction();
    }
}
```

Initially I got data in ResultSet.
Transactions was helping me to insert this bunch of records very fast.

Now I want to use **content provider** in my program, and I am thinking how to implement my methods with it.

So how should I now insert my records in tables? Only one-by-one?

Can I pass (if it is the right way) resultset to content provider to insert records?

Answer (score 0):

override bulkInsert in your ContentProvider